# Why compareTo param is allways null when sorting a List

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, compareto

Here is my code in ManagedBean:

```
public List posortujGrupe(Set<Uczestnik> sm) {
    List sortedList2 = new ArrayList(sm);
    System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^1");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sortedList2.size() ; i++)
        System.out.println("i: "+i+" -> "+((Uczestnik)(sortedList2.get(i))).getStatusUczestnictwa());
    System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^2");
    Collections.sort(sortedList2);
    return sortedList2;
}
```

It should sort the list that is displayed in  in jsf page

Here is my code in Uczestnik Class:

```
public class Uczestnik  implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<Uczestnik> {
     (...)
     private String statusUczestnictwa;
     (...)
     public Uczestnik(..., String statusUczestnictwa, ...){
          (...)
          this.statusUczestnictwa = statusUczestnictwa;
          (...)
     }

     (...)

     public String getStatusUczestnictwa() {
          return this.statusUczestnictwa;
     }

     public void setStatusUczestnictwa(String statusUczestnictwa) {
         this.statusUczestnictwa = statusUczestnictwa;
     }

     (...)

     @Override
     public int compareTo(Uczestnik o) {
          System.out.println("0: "+ o.statusUczestnictwa);
          System.out.println("t: "+ this.statusUczestnictwa);
          if(o.statusUczestnictwa == null || this.statusUczestnictwa == null){
              if(o.statusUczestnictwa == null && this.statusUczestnictwa == null)
                    return 0;
              else{
                  if(o.statusUczestnictwa == null)
                       return 1;
                  else
                       return -1;
              }
          }   
          else{
              if(o.statusUczestnictwa == null && this.statusUczestnictwa == null)
                   return 0;
              else
                   return this.statusUczestnictwa.compareTo(o.statusUczestnictwa);
          }
     }
 }
```

It is genateted class by hibernate where i added Comparable.

And this is my output in console:

```
^^^^^^^^^^1
i: 0 -> 2
i: 1 -> 3
i: 2 -> 4
i: 3 -> 1
^^^^^^^^^^2
0: null
t: 3
0: null
t: 4
0: null
t: 1
```

All "o" objects of Uczestniks in compareTo function in Uczestnik class always are null.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I do the same with other class and it works fine, i don't know what is wrong here ...

Comment: @geert3 it works, thanks a lot. Still didn't know why in one class it must be get and in other one not ... strange.

Comment: changed my comment to answer so you can close the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `o.statusUczestnictwa` with `o.getStatusUczestnictwa()` inside the `compareTo`. Perhaps there is some hibernate lazy loading that is messing with you.